How do you correctly add dependencies for Dagger Hilt in Android Studio Iguana?
I tried to add the dependencies for Dagger Hilt, but I can't seem to add them correctly. Everywhere I've looked, I only found instructions for adding them with the old dependency system.
I tried adding them using the old method, but it doesn't seem to work.
I am beginner on developing android apps and will really help if someone know how to do that :)

did you solved that issue? I am also facing the same thing. Kindly let me know.

This is how I add (hilt) dependencies in Android Studio Iguana/Jellyfish using version catalogs:
In your app level build.gradle.kts plugin section:
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.androidApplication)
    alias(libs.plugins.jetbrainsKotlinAndroid)
    alias(libs.plugins.jetbrainsKotlinKsp)
    alias(libs.plugins.hiltPlugin)
}

dependencies section:
dependencies {
    implementation(libs.androidx.core.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.appcompat)
    implementation(libs.androidx.lifecycle.runtime.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.activity.compose)

    //Hilt
    implementation (libs.hilt.android)
    ksp(libs.dagger.compiler)
    ksp(libs.hilt.compiler)

    testImplementation(libs.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.espresso.core)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.ui.test.junit4)
    debugImplementation(libs.androidx.ui.tooling)
    debugImplementation(libs.androidx.ui.test.manifest)
}

In your project level build.gradle.kts:
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.androidApplication) apply false
    alias(libs.plugins.jetbrainsKotlinAndroid) apply false
    alias(libs.plugins.jetbrainsKotlinKsp) apply false
    alias(libs.plugins.hiltPlugin) apply false
}

In your libs.versions.toml file:
[versions]
agp = "8.3.2"
appcompat = "1.6.1"
hiltAndroid = "2.51"
kotlin = "1.9.0"
kotlinKsp = "1.9.0-1.0.12"
coreKtx = "1.13.1"
junit = "4.13.2"
junitVersion = "1.1.5"
espressoCore = "3.5.1"
lifecycleRuntimeKtx = "2.8.0"
activityCompose = "1.9.0"

[libraries]
androidx-appcompat = { module = "androidx.appcompat:appcompat", version.ref = "appcompat" }
androidx-core-ktx = { group = "androidx.core", name = "core-ktx", version.ref = "coreKtx" }

dagger-compiler = { module = "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler", version.ref = "hiltAndroid" }
hilt-android = { module = "com.google.dagger:hilt-android", version.ref = "hiltAndroid" }
hilt-compiler = { module = "com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler", version.ref = "hiltAndroid" }

junit = { group = "junit", name = "junit", version.ref = "junit" }
androidx-junit = { group = "androidx.test.ext", name = "junit", version.ref = "junitVersion" }
androidx-espresso-core = { group = "androidx.test.espresso", name = "espresso-core", version.ref = "espressoCore" }
androidx-lifecycle-runtime-ktx = { group = "androidx.lifecycle", name = "lifecycle-runtime-ktx", version.ref = "lifecycleRuntimeKtx" }
androidx-activity-compose = { group = "androidx.activity", name = "activity-compose", version.ref = "activityCompose" }

[plugins]
androidApplication = { id = "com.android.application", version.ref = "agp" }
jetbrainsKotlinAndroid = { id = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android", version.ref = "kotlin" }
jetbrainsKotlinKsp = { id = "com.google.devtools.ksp", version.ref = "kotlinKsp" }
hiltPlugin = { id = "com.google.dagger.hilt.android", version.ref = "hiltAndroid" }

Ref:
Gradle Build Setup
Hope that helps!
